# Parallelizing a function using ´foreach´ and ´doParallel´

Tags: r, foreach, doparallel

Im trying to parallelize a function, but Im running into problems.

Basically, Im running the function `manysimulations` over a `desig_grid`

This is my main function (it works if I don't do any parallelization):

```
    manyimulations_gamma <- function(design_grid){
      
      sim_results_pilot_study_gamma <- matrix(nrow = nrow(design_grid), ncol = 12)
      
      colnames(sim_results_pilot_study_gamma) = c(
        "estimate_x1ij_lmer_model_4p",
        "std.err_x1ij_lmer_model_4p",
        "p_x1ij_lmer_model_4p",       
        "estimate_z1j_lmer_model_4p",
        "std.err_z1j_lmer_model_4p",
        "p_z1j_lmer_model_4p",        
        "estimate_x2ij_lmer_model_4p",
        "std.err_x2ij_lmer_model_4p",
        "p_x2ij_lmer_model_4p",       
        "estimate_z2j_lmer_model_4p",
        "std.err_z2j_lmer_model_4p",
        "p_z2j_lmer_model_4p"
      )
      
      sim_results_pilot_study_gamma <- as.data.frame(sim_results_pilot_study_gamma)
      
      for(i in 1:nrow(design_grid)){
        res<- one_simulation_gamma(ni = design_grid$ni[i],
                                    nj = design_grid$nj[i],
                                    gamma02 = design_grid$gamma02[i],
                                    gamma20 = design_grid$gamma20[i],
                                    RI_sd = design_grid$RI_sd[i])
        
        
        sim_results_pilot_study_gamma[i,] <- res
         
      }

  
 # sim_results_pilot_study_gamma<- cbind(sim_results_pilot_study_gamma, design_grid)
  
  return(sim_results_pilot_study_gamma)
  
}
```

I basically just create a matrix (`sim_results_pilot_study_gamma`), hand the values of the `design_grid` to another function (`one_simulation_gamma`), and read back the results into the matrix.

My `design_grid` looks like this:

```
 head(design_grid)
  ni nj     RI_sd gamma02 gamma20 replication ID
1 30 30 0.3333333     0.5     0.5           1  1
2 30 30 0.5000000     0.5     0.5           1  2
3 30 30 0.6546537     0.5     0.5           1  3
4 30 30 0.8164966     0.5     0.5           1  4
5 30 30 1.0000000     0.5     0.5           1  5
6 30 30 1.2247449     0.5     0.5           1  6
```

Ive tried to use this code to parallelize the function:

```
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)
    
number_cores = 4
    
doParallel::registerDoParallel(number_cores)

# run simulation
start <- Sys.time() # for microbenchmarking
temp_result <- foreach (i = seq_len(number_cores),.packages="lme4") %dopar% { # %dopar% evaluates in parallel
   manyimulations_gamma(design_grid = design_grid)
   #main function
}
Sys.time()-start

# stop cluster
doParallel::stopImplicitCluster()
```

An I get this error:

> Error in { : task 1 failed - "error in evaluating the argument 'x' in
> selecting a method for function 't': subscript out of bounds"

The problem when parallelizing is -I think - that I try to run the whole `design_grid` over all 4 cores simultaneously instead of only a part of the `design_grid` as I intend...

Has anyone an idea on how I could fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely clear on what you are trying to achieve, but it seems like you may want to run `one_simulation_gamma` rather than `manysimulations_gamma` in parallel?

Should the ith parallel job take the ith row of `design_grid` and feed it into `one_simulation_gamma`?

If that's what you're trying to do then you need something like

```
foreach (i = seq(nrow(design_grid)), .combine = rbind) %dopar% { 
    one_simulation_gamma(
       ni = design_grid$ni[i],
       nj = design_grid$nj[i],
       gamma02 = design_grid$gamma02[i],
       gamma20 = design_grid$gamma20[i],
       RI_sd = design_grid$RI_sd[i]
    )
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I want to do. So that every line of the `design_grid` is fed to the `one_simulation_gamma`. I tried your solution, yet I still get the same error. This is the function `one_simulation_gamma` Im using (give the data to a `lmer` function and read back the coefficient).

`one_simulation_gamma <- function(ni,nj,gamma02,gamma20,RI_sd) {
  dgp_grid <-dgp_pilot_study_gamma(ni,nj,RI_sd,gamma02,gamma20)
  #creating the data
  
  res_lmer_function_model_2 <- lmer_function(dgp_grid, model = 2)
  #lmer.  linear models for mixed effects
  
  return(res_lmer_function_model_2)
}`